# Custom function to add a note to the Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying to write a simple custom function to allow a cell to contain some text, and then have additional information in a note, something like this:

[image: example]

My code at the moment is:

```js
function TEXTNOTE(celltext, notetext) {
  setNote(notetext);
  return celltext;
}
```

This returns an error, because [`setNote`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote) isn't defined - so I assume that I need `[something].setNote` - but what should `[something]` be?

Comment: I apologize that I had thought your function of `setNote()` was created for putting the note by you. But I think that existing answer will resolve your issue.

Comment: For documentation purposes, please accept the answer that helped you the most. This will help future readers and community.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

I understand you want to use a custom function. However, there is the following limitation:

> [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) and [setNote()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote) are functions that require
> authorization by the user, namely you **can not** call them within
> **custom functions** (see **References**).

### Solutions:

1. You can **click** on the cell of interest and then execute the following function:

   ```
   function TEXTNOTE(){

   const celltext = "Cell title";
   const notetext = "Note text" ;
   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
   const cc = sheet.getCurrentCell();
   cc.setNote(notetext);
   sheet.getRange(cc.getA1Notation()).setValue(celltext);}
   ```
2. If you want to specify the cell (let's say A1) within the script and **you don't want to click on it**, then you can just run the following:

   ```
   function TEXTNOTE(){

   const celltext = "Cell title";
   const notetext = "Note text" ;
   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
   const cc = sheet.getRange('A1');
   cc.setNote(notetext);
   cc.setValue(celltext);}
   ```

**Side Notes:**

- You can execute the aforementioned functions either by clicking on
  the play button in the script editor or you can create a custom
  sidebar menu that will allow you to execute the function from the
  spreadsheet file.
- If you want to perform this task iteratively, then you need to
  provide a list of **titles** and **notes** and run a loop to apply
  this operation to every cell. If you want the values of `celltext`
  and `notetext` to be retrieved from your script you will have to
  create two dedicated columns to provide this information.

### Example:

[image: example]

### References:

From the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask
> users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can
> only call services that do not have access to personal data.

Comment: The first version returns two lines of text, and the second version gives an error (Error
ReferenceError: setNote is not defined (line 2).)

Comment: I've updated a question to show what I'd like the output to be. setNote is part of the Google Apps Script API, it certainly works with [cellreference].setNote("Note text") just fine.

Comment: That's closer, but I want to see if there's something that can run as a calculation-style function - for example "note text" may well not be a simple string, so I don't want the user to have to click on it to update it (a mouse-over event might work, however the sheet is already fairly large so that may well slow things down a lot).

Comment: @MattBowyer you understand that this is a different question. You now need to provide 3 columns. One column will be the `title` , the second column will be `note text` and the third one will be the desired cell you want to edit. If you don't want this structure, then you have to pass the title and note text in your script itself. But this is another question.

Comment: I updated my answer, solution 2 does not require to click on the cell. @MattBowyer