# Googlesheets - Vlookup text to place into a note

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup

I'm trying to iteratively vlookup another sheet and placing the contents into the notes

**WORKSHEET: PROJECT_DESCRIPTION**

| Project Name | Project Description |
| --- | --- |
| Project 123 | Note 123 |
| Project 456 | Note 456 |

**WORKSHEET: PROJECT_DISPLAY**

| Project Name |
| --- |
| Project 123 <-- note shown on hover over would be "Note 123" |
| Project 456 <-- note shown on hover over would be "Note 456" |

Apologies I'm new to scripting (think this is the only way to do this) but if you know of a simpler way, please feel free to share.

Thanks so much.

Was able to find this post to help but not sure how to incorporate the vlookup or iteration element:
[Custom function to add a note to the Google Sheets cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587851/custom-function-to-add-a-note-to-the-google-sheets-cell)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. The logic is:

- using `indexOf`, take the Project name from `PROJECT_DESCRIPTION` and search for a match on `PROJECT_DISPLAY`

  - `IndexOf`: returns -1 if no match, or the row index number on "PROJECT_DISPLAY" if there is a match
- use a temporary array to store the value of the Note
- if the Project name from `PROJECT_DESCRIPTION` can't be matched on `PROJECT_DISPLAY`, then there is no update to the Notes.
- `setNotes` using the temporary array to assign Notes to each cell in the range

---

```
function setNotes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var display = ss.getSheetByName("PROJECT_DISPLAY")
  var description = ss.getSheetByName("PROJECT_DESCRIPTION")

  // get description sheet data
  var descriptions = description.getDataRange().getValues()
  // remove the header row
  descrData = descriptions.splice(1,descriptions.length-1)

  // get the display data
  var displayLR = display.getLastRow()
  var displayRange = display.getRange(2,1,displayLR-1)
  var displayData = displayRange.getValues()
  var displayNotes = displayRange.getNotes()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: display range = "+displayRange.getA1Notation())
  // Logger.log(displayData) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(displayNotes) // DEBUG
  var displayColA = displayData.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  // Logger.log(displayColA) // DEBUG

  // create temporary array for Notes
  var noteValues = []

  // loop through the projects on "PROJECT_DESCRIPTION"
  // indexOf returns -1 if can't find the "Project name", or the row number of "DISPLAY" if it can.
  for (var i=0;i<descrData.length;i++){
    var result = displayColA.indexOf(descrData[i][0]);
    if (result != -1){
      Logger.log("DEBUG: MATCH: i:"+i+", project = "+descrData[i][0]+", result = "+result+", note = "+displayNotes[result][0]+" new note "+descrData[i][1])
      noteValues[result]=[descrData[i][1]]
    }
    else{
      // can't find project on DISPLAY sheet
      Logger.log("DEBUG: NO MATCH: i:"+i+", project = "+descrData[i][0]+", result = "+result)
      
    }
  }
  // Logger.log(noteValues) // DEBUG
  displayRange.setNotes(noteValues)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! really appreciate all the comments and time you have taken to create / share this.

Comment: @jjson Just realised that IF there is a project name on "PROJECT DISPLAY" that is NOT on "PROJECT DESCRIPTION", then it will throw a spanner into the works. Is that a possibibility?

Comment: If this script worked well for you, then you might care to “Accept” it as an answer.